# UnhandledException 0x8000ffff while navigating pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, unhandled-exception

I am new to WP7 application and facing a strange issue. My application crashes when I navigate from one page to other. It works for a specific scenario and fails in other two cases.
I am attaching source code for reference and hoping for a solution. I also looked at the other thread to see what am I doing wrong but could not find it. Here are steps to generate the issue:

- After running the application, click on “Water” and page will navigate to “WebPage.xaml” and will load respective web content.
- Now click on “Back” button on the emulator, you will get same scree with “Water” and its description.
- It works as expected.
- Now click on arrow pointing towards “Right”, a new content will load on same “MainPage.xaml” with details of “Methane”.
- Click on “Methane” to navigate and load “WebPage.xaml” with web content of “Methane”.
- Now click on “Back” button on emulator and application crashes. I am wondering same process or steps works fine with “Water” and fails for “Methane”.

Here is the Inner Exception caught... "Could not evaluate expression"
and Stack Trace...

```
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
    at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
    at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight)
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
    at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
    at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

Comment: Paste your code here rather than uploading it anywhere else. Also follow this thread : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Well I am not sure which portion of code is generating exception and it will be easy for someone to take a look at the entire project instead of a portion of code.

Comment: Can you catch the exception and paste the inner exception and stackstrace?

Comment: Updated the post to add inner exception and stacktrace...

Comment: @user433543: Sorry, our users aren't your debug team; asking them to go offsite, download compile and debug your application isn't allowed.  What you *do* need to do, is create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) which reproduces your issue, and post that here.  Most likely, in doing so you'll figure out what you did wrong the first time.